# CMake use rpath for linked libraries instead of the full path

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, dynamic-linking, rpath

For simplicity, here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(example)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC objc)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

After building it, I run the following command:
`otool -L libexample.dylib` which outputs:

```
libexample.dylib:
    @rpath/libexample.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.50.4)
```

Is there anything that could be done through CMake to cause the linking to the objc library to use rpath instead of the full path? `@rpath/libobjc.A.dylib` instead of `/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib`

Edit:
I've tried the solution for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330165/how-to-link-a-shared-library-with-cmake-with-relative-path), but it doesn't seem to fix my issue. The output of the `otool` command remains the same.

Edit 2:
The following example still links to the full path and not the rpath:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(example)

set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH TRUE)
set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_DIR "@rpath/")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
        LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
        LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath,./"
        MACOSX_RPATH TRUE
        SKIP_BUILD_RPATH FALSE
        BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE
        INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE
        INSTALL_NAME_DIR "@rpath/")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC objc)
```

Edit 3:

With further investigation, I've come to the conclusion that this wouldn't be possible without using `install_name_tool -change`. From this [issue](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15708), it appears that for any external libraries (outside the build tree) the resulting linking path will be whatever the id of the library is (use: `otool -D /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib` to find the id of the lib).

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43333118/499581

Comment: Tried the solution in that question, but when I inspect the dylib, the result is the same. As a workaround, I could use `install_name_tool -change`, but it'd be much cleaner if CMake had a way of doing this in place.

Comment: I totally agree that it would be cleaner than using `install_name_tool` each time. Which methods did you try on the linked question/answer? There seem to be multiple methods outlined. From my understanding `SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH FALSE)` would be the main override for excluding the full pathname.

Comment: I tried quite a few combinations from that answer, and also from this link: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling but still no luck. I suppose something to note is that I'm looking for this to work after the build step (not install).

Comment: Since you are wanting this for the build stage then  `SET(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE) # when building, don't use the install RPATH already
# (but later on when installing)` and 
`SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)` is what you would use. You can also try `INSTALL_NAME_DIR` and `MACOSX_RPATH`...

Comment: The key section in the documentation I believe you'll want to look at is titled **Default RPATH settings**.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the documentation addresses this issue, but the fix outlined there doesn't seem to work from my experience with it. I've amended the question with an additional non-working example.

Comment: You have `CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH` set to `TRUE` when it should be `FALSE`; same with `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170185/discussion-between-vejmartin-and-lll).