# how to let executables load a system library, e.g. libpng from local path

Tags: c++, cmake

I got a cpp game client like this in macOS:

```
$ otool -L ./XXXGameClient
./XXXGameClient:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.50.4)
    @rpath/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2 (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 22.0.0)
    @rpath/SDL2_image.framework/Versions/A/SDL2_image (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 3.1.0)
    @rpath/SDL2_mixer.framework/Versions/A/SDL2_mixer (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.1.0)
    @rpath/SDL2_ttf.framework/Versions/A/SDL2_ttf (compatibility version 15.0.0, current version 15.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.11)
    /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib (compatibility version 52.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.0)
    @rpath/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
```

The game client have dependency of libpng with a full path, i want to distribute the `libpng` binary to the executable directory and the it load the lib correctly, just like the SDL2 do with RPATH feature.

How could I do it?

Comment: I use the Framework version fo SDL2 libs, and cmake automatically use RPATH for me. So I can ship the sdl2 framework with game client binary. I want the libpng do the same.

Comment: [related or even duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330165/how-to-link-a-shared-library-with-cmake-with-relative-path)?

Comment: Look into RPATH.

Comment: I have set rpath already: set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH FALSE)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE). I think libpng is library in system path, rpath won't work. And hombrew version libpng is not capable to work with rpath, since the lib has dependency of `/usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib`

Comment: `$ otool -L /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
/usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib:
 /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib (compatibility version 52.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
 /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.11)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.50.4)`